# How to send Custom Object with Send-MailMessage using PowerShell?

Tags: html, powershell, outlook, sendmail

I've removed the names of the servers but I am trying to send a table (as seen in the image) to a group of admins if something is wrong with the server/services.

The error message I get in PowerShell is

```
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
```

Is there any built-in method to send the Object to look like the formatted table as we see in the image below? If not can someone tell me how to use custom objects to create my own table?

Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want a string that looks like the output you see in the console, use `Out-String`.

```
$bodyString = $object | Out-String
```

Comment: This did work but the formatting was not preserved when attempting to email. I don't mind building an html table but I don't know how to access the data in each cell.

Comment: @softwareisfun the formatting didn't work because you're using an HTML body, and whitespace is collapsed in HTML. You can try to embed it in `<pre></pre>` tags, or use a plain text body.